# Am I asking too many questions at once?

Tags: support, questions, meta

I am embarrassed to see that the top five questions on board are not only mine, but I was the last one active in each of them.  This will make the sixth.  Could someone tell me if I am being too pushy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a limit of 50 questions per 30 day period on this site (not counting "closed" or deleted questions). Otherwise, you can ask all you want.

There are some people that "dominate" (or seem to) certain topics. (Yours truly for one.) Others will disagree with me, but I don't think that's bad. The site is just in its infancy, so one person (particularly an active one) could easily have a disproportionate impact SOMEWHERE on the site.

In my opinion, we have too FEW questions on the site. The more questions, the more possibilities for answering (reputation: 10, instead of 5), the more chances for more people to gain reputation. Also, the more "authoritative" the site will seem on a certain topic.

Answer (score 1):

People used to jump all over new users for asking generic SE questions on site-specific metas, but that stopped a while ago -- you can ask any questions about the site here, even if they apply to all SE sites. Now that you know about meta.SO, you're welcome to ask there as well, and it's probably better (odds are high that the question has already been asked, so it can be closed as a duplicate there), but it's not "wrong" to ask here

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's more than I knew!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured that this is not The Site to ask most of my meta questions on; Meta StackOverflow is The Site.  To a new user, the status of the SO meta site alongside the name it has can be confusing.

Comment: This is no longer true.  All of your questions are welcome here, or at meta.so, whichever you prefer.  As Michael noted, this is a recent network wide policy change.  It was made specifically because it *is* confusing, and unreasonable to expect every user of every SE site to know about meta.SO.  Heck, just noticing that meta.bcd exists and using it is a lot to expect for new users :-)